# how to show button after 1 min of page loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show button after 1 min of page is loaded which will locate in middle of the page but it will only show on text1. I'm trying to split one page into two so text1 and text2 will be one full page while text1 displays the text2 will be hidden and text2 will only show up if the button is clicked any help will be appreciated.

```
<div id="text1">Cat</div>
<div id="text2">Dog</div>

<button onclick="Function()">Display text 2</button>
```

Comment: just added simple button

Answer (score 1):

Run the code snippet. Button will display after 1 minute.

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myButton').show();
  }, 60000);
  $('#myButton').click(function() {
    $('#text1').hide();
    $('#text2').show();
  });
});
```

```css
#text2,
#myButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text1">Cat<button id="myButton">Next Page</button></div>
<div id="text2">Dog</div>
```

Fiddle for 3 seconds: http://jsfiddle.net/3s192nq8/2/

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript add:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // Code to display your button
}, 60000);
```

It will be executed after 1 min (60 000 miliseconds).